# Jenkins-cli.jar is corrupted when I run docker file in bash

Tags: docker, jenkins, command-line-interface

I  need to build the dockerfile that downloads jenkins.war and through it jenkins-cli.jar need to be downloaded.
I have conf.xml also to configure it.**
Then I need that image to run in the bash, which needs to run that jar file commands.
Here is the code:

```
    FROM ubuntu:14.04
    RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y  software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y && \
    apt-get update && \
    echo oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1          select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get install -f -y oracle-java8-installer && \
    apt install -y default-jre curl wget git nano; \
    apt-get clean


    # Install dependencies
    RUN apt-get -y update  && \
    apt-get -yqq --no-install-recommends install git bzip2 curl unzip && \
    apt-get update

    ENV JAVA_HOME /usr
    ENV PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

    # copy jenkins war file to the container
    ADD http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war-stable/2.107.1/jenkins.war /opt/jenkins.war
    RUN chmod 644 /opt/jenkins.war
    ENV JENKINS_HOME /jenkins

    # configure the container to run jenkins, mapping container port 8080 to that host port
    RUN mkdir /jenkins/
    RUN echo 2.107.1 > /jenkins/jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state
    RUN echo 2.107.1 > /jenkins/jenkins.install.InstallUtil.lastExecVersion
    CMD ["nohup","java", "-jar", "/opt/jenkins.war"]
    EXPOSE 8080
    VOLUME /jenkins
    #COPY jenkins-cli.jar /jenkins/jenkins-cli.jar

    #jenkins-cli installation
    ENV JENKINS_URL "http://192.168.99.100:8080"
    RUN curl --insecure http://192.168.99.100:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar \
       --output /jenkins/jenkins-cli.jar
    CMD ["java","-jar","/jenkins/jenkins-cli.jar","-noCertificateCheck","-noKeyAuth"]
```

Here is what im getting.
[image: ERROR]

**MY ASSUMPTION** 
Do I need to run along congf.xml?If yes , then HOW?
Do I need to be running jenkins.war instance in background??? HOW?
Thank you in advance

[image: versions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the [reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) , I can find those comments.

`There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect.`

in your dockerfile, there are multiple `CMD` commands. only the last one will be executed.

If you want to run multiple commands at once. try bash scripts. here is the [example](https://github.com/nberserk/armhf-hadoop-multinode/blob/master/hadoop-master/bootstrap.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting sshd"
exec /usr/sbin/sshd -D &

if [ -z "$1" ];
then
    tail -f $HADOOP_INSTALL/logs/*
fi
```

Comment: Can i make Entrypoint the first CMD command and try? @Darren Ha

Comment: @Hithesh No. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile

Comment: THank you for info @Darren Ha